# How do I automatically refresh a gridview in asp.net webform after a button click while the onclick method is still processing on the server side?

Tags: asp.net

I have a two column asp.net webform. The form is the on the left side and the gridview is on the right side. When a user clicks on a button, there is a method on the server side that will process a list of items. I want to show the results in the gridview on the right as each item in the list is processed. I also want to disable a bunch of controls on my page after the button click and enable them once the entire list is processed.

Thanks!

Comment: U have to populate the datasource of the grid with new data and call databind.

Comment: That would not update the page while the rest of the list is still being processed though.

Comment: Show your code (markup + code behind), there is too little information in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

make use of client side/javascript.
e.g. run a client side loop on button click, take the first item from gridview process it, update the second gridview and repeat.